# Xamarin XAML Data Binding "OneWayToSource"

Tags: xamarin, data-binding

I came across this Xamarin blog post about data binding, and though I have read it multiple times, part of it doesn't make any sense to me.

https://blog.xamarin.com/introduction-to-data-binding/

Can anyone clarify the difference between OneWay and OneWayToSource?

The text states the following:

"A OneWay binding propagates changes from the source to the target." (but not back)

If there is no flow back, wouldn't that be he definition of a read-only property? Unfortunately, a bit further down, the author says:

"A OneWayToSource binding propagates changes from the target to the source, and is mainly used for read-only bindable properties."

If a change appers at the target (=view), and propagates to the source - how can this be a read-only property?

Who can clarify?

Answer (score 1):

> A OneWay binding propagates changes from the **source** to the **target**.

OneWayToSource is the **opposite** of OneWay

> A OneWayToSource binding propagates changes from the **target** to the **source**

Comment: That's exactly what I don't understand. If OneWay lets changes propagate from source (=the Model) to target (=the View) only, but not back, any changes made at the View would get lost.

If so, a OneWay property may be bound for display purposes, but not change --> a read-only property.

Comment: Typically OneWay is the default mechanism used for Labels and other UI elements that user CANNOT make changes to, so there is no need for the source to be updated.

Comment: Yes, one would think so. But the documentation (see link in my original post) seems to state the opposite. "OneWayToSource [...] is mainly used for read-only bindable properties."

Answer (score 1):

So with a View-ViewModel Relationship.

OneWay binding is binding from the View Model (Source) to the View (Target).
This property cannot be change once it is set by the ViewModel (Source)

Whereas

OneWayToSource binding is from the View (Target) to the ViewModel (Source).
This property cannot be change once it is set by the View (Target)

I can provide examples of each case if you are still having trouble understanding.

Comment: Please see my comment to Jason's response. I know the definition, but somewhere in my mind I have a twist: I'd expect the OneWay binding to be used to populate a read-only property.